# java.lang.ClassCastException: - Arrays.asList()

Tags: java, arrays, collections, classcastexception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>
> java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList  at BinarySearch.main(BinarySearch.java:14)

below is my code-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class BinarySearch{
    public static void main(String s[]) throws InterruptedException{
        int result=-1;
        Integer[] array ={34,67,12,32,07,11,25} ;

           ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
           list=(ArrayList<Integer>) Arrays.asList(array);
           for(Integer i:list) 
               System.out.println(i);
        Collections.sort(list);
           for(Integer i:list) 
               System.out.println(i);
           int search=new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        int low=0;
        int max=list.size()-1;
        int middle=(low+max)/2;
        System.out.println(low+" - "+middle+" - "+max );
        while(low<=max){
        if(list.get(middle)== search){
            result=middle;
            break;
        }else if(list.get(middle)> search){
            max=middle-1;
        }else{
            low=middle+1;
        }
        middle=(low+max)/2;
        System.out.println(low+" - "+middle+" - "+max );
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
        }
        if(result==-1)
        System.out.println("not Found!");
        else System.out.println("Element "+search+" found at position- "+result);

    }

}
```

If I explore above problem-

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array)); 
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(array);
List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list2);
```

am I right?

**list1 and list3 have have behavior while list2 is immutable.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List` that is returned by [`Arrays.asList(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) is not a [`java.util.ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), so you get a `ClassCastException` if you try to cast it to `ArrayList`, as you are doing here:

```
list=(ArrayList<Integer>) Arrays.asList(array);
```

Solution: Don't cast it to `ArrayList`. Use the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface instead.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) returns `List`, not an `ArrayList`.

Change:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list = (ArrayList<Integer>) Arrays.asList(array);
```

to

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Comment: I would recommend against creating the `ArrayList` as it is a wasted instantiation.

Comment: why create an empty ArrayList in the second example?

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.asList` doesn't return a `java.util.ArrayList`.

Either use the `List` interface instead of a specific implementation :

```
       List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Or create a `java.util.ArrayList` instance and pass the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` to its constructor :

```
       ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer> (Arrays.asList(array));
```